# Mysql master-master replication using blackhole engine

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave, blackhole

I've got a master-slave mysql replication using blackhole engine for some tables on slave, so I'm wondering what will happen if I enable master-master replication? 
Will the tables become empty on my 1st master?

Comment: Have you researched anything so far?

Comment: Yup, figured out that these tables wont become empty on first master

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: they won't.
Replication simply ignoring my blackhole tables.
What I have done to test this:
Set up docker container with the mysql db.
Created a copy of the db to another docker mysql container.
Enabled master-master replication on both dbs.
Added some different data to both dbs.
Changed engine of the couple of tables with BLACKHOLE on the second master.
Then I added some different data to both dbs, and checked that on the first master there were no changes in tables that has the BLACKHOLE engine on the second master.